# UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell gets populated with data only after swiping

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm using [this](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) method of displaying a UICollectionView inside a  UITableViewCell. It's being populated with data from an API, using JSON. My problem with it however is, that when the view initially loads, it contains no data (just blank labels etc). It populates whenever I swipe the collection view. Can anyone suggest a potential solution? The one I found was to reload data inside viewDidLoad, but it doesn't work in that case.

Comment: cant you reloadData either on the API call success or on the willDisplayCell?

Comment: show me your code

Comment: Sean, reloading collection view data in TableView's willDisplayCell didn't help. And reloadData is called on API call success.

Comment: Ganesh, which part? It's quite a large codebase (and quite NDA'd as well).

Comment: @michalronin collectionView code